# Syntax of redirection the stderr and stdout to dev/null

Tags: bash, syntax, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I want to redirect the stderr and stdout to dev/null.
Which ist the correct way to redirect and is there difference betweent these options?
I have seen in internet two syntax:

1. `command &>/dev/null` (without space)
2. `command &> /dev/null` (with space)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: For convention, though: https://github.com/git/git/commit/92014b69bb1aa781605295e0e0d3d886368bb7a3

Answer (score 3):

Bash allows spaces around a [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) operator, so both forms are valid.

That said, you can't use spaces between parts of more complex redirection operators, e.g:

```
command 2> /dev/null   # ok
command 2 > /dev/null  # wrong, the operator is '2>'
command 2> &1          # wrong, the operator is '2>&1'
```